# Как записать в куки, затем успешно выводить при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, cookie

Сам я не очень владею ни js ни Jquery, интуитивно могу понять смысл скрипта, но какие-то глобальные операции производить пока не умею! Рассчитываю на Вашу помощь!
Имеется небольшая форма с двумя номерами - Питера и Москвы.

```
<div class="switch-contacts">
                            <div class="contacts-active">
                                <div class="contacts-item active"><strong class="comagic_phone_msk">+123 456 78 90</strong><small>Москва</small></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="contacts-noactive">
                                <div class="contacts-item"><strong class="comagic_phone_spb">+987 654 32 10</strong><small>Питер</small></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

А также Jquery код который позволяет менять значения:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.switch-contacts .active').click(function() {
        $('.contacts-noactive').slideToggle(100);
        $(this).toggleClass('focus');
    });

    $('.contacts-noactive .contacts-item').click(function() {
        var contentItem = $(this).html();
        var contentActiveItem = $('.switch-contacts .active').html();
        $('.switch-contacts .active').html(contentItem);
        $(this).html(contentActiveItem);
        $('.contacts-noactive').slideToggle(100);
        $('.switch-contacts .active').toggleClass('focus');
    });

}); 
</script>
```

По умолчанию, после перезагрузки страницы всегда - Москва, но как с помощью  `$.cookie('phone', 'Current Phone');` выбранное значение записалось в куки, а затем успешно вывелось после перезагрузки?! Заранее, огромное спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

```
cookie

$.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', {
        expires: 5,  //длительность в днях 
        path: '/',  // область доступности
    });
```

`LocalStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('ключ', 'значение')
```

Метод который добавляет в localStorage новый ключ со значением (а если такой ключ уже существует, то перезаписывает новым значением). Пишем, например, localStorage.setItem(‘myKey’, ‘myValue’);

```
localStorage.getItem('ключ')
```

Берем определенное значение из хранилища по ключу.

```
localStorage.removeItem("Ключ")
```

Удаляем ключ

```
localStorage.clear()
```

Очищаем все хранилище

Comment: Это все хорошо, но тут необходимо решить именно с помощью кук на Jquery! Это не трудно, насколько я знаю, просто у знающего человека это займет 2 минуты, а у меня пол дня))

Comment: первый попавшийся сайт все наглядно показывает